# Run Google App script function after third party edit is finished

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Bardeen as an automation tool to bring my Notion databases into Google Sheets.
I then have an Apps Script function that formats some data.
I want that function to run each time Bardeen changes the Google Sheet values.
I tried all simple triggers `onEdit()`, `doGet()` etc and none of them seem to do the job.
Is there another way?

I also tried add on trigger "on change" but that means whenever my Apps Script changed something it would run again. Also if I changed anything in a second sheet (for charts) the code would run again.

Comment: Yes onEdit is only for user edits and onChange will work on some script access with the changeType of other but the event object is very limited. doGet() is not really intended to be a general purpose trigger. It is meant to serve as an endpoint for webapps

Comment: Still haven't found a way to do this. i basically need to set it and forget it. i don't want to have open this document to update it. i need the functions to run when it get updated by Bardeen automation tool

Comment: Well that way I would do is either with an on Open or I'd simply run the function from the menu.  Yeah it requires wait for a short time but I'm okay with that because I like to avoid the unnecessary use of the server.  It's your call.  However, if you used onChange with changeType == "OTHER" that might actually work for you.  I'm not that familiar with what the unique subclass of actions that responds to is.

Comment: In my experence it reacts the things like import and change triggered by other scripts.  I don't think it will respond to most user edits but I could be wrong you will just have to try and the come back and teach the rest of us by what you have learned

Comment: alright, i guess i will give onChange() another shot, maybe i've missed something. Last time i used onChange() it was triggering with every change, not just the Bardeen automation but also the app scripts it triggered. i will have another look at that now that my code is a bit cleaner.

Comment: The trigger will trigger on every situation that it's design to trigger on but you have the ability to only run your function on the ones that have a changeType == "OTHER" by doing something like `if(changeType == "OTHER"){//run script in here}`